# Insert into Oracle table from excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to read the data from excel and insert into existing Oracle table. The file size is 15MB. I have to map the excel column name to table column name. Before that I need to truncate the table.

The excel has

```
            Name
            Number
             Age
```

The Oracle table has

```
         EMPLOYEE{
              ID
              EMP_NAME
              EMP_AGE
              EMP_ADDRESS
              CREATED_DATE
             }
```

Now I need to map the columns

NAME=> EMP_NAME, AGE=> EMP_AGE

```
      TRUNCATE TABLE EMPLOYEE;
      LOAD DATA{ EXCEL}
       INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(  )//THIS SHOULD ALSO CREATE ID AND ADD THE CURRDATE() AS CREATED DATE;
       COMMIT;
```

I am actually stuck here and need to some help to proceed further. I HAVE AROUND 300000 ROWS IN EXCEL

Thanks in advance

Comment: save as csv and use external table

Comment: It sounds like very general question. What the tool do you want to use? Did you try data import available in SQL Developer? Do you have an access to the server OS to use external table?

Comment: No I don't have the access. Its like I need to share the script with DB team. Sometimes Admin also wants to run this. So I do not want to use import in sql developer. This is also similar to migration that happens yearly once until legacy is sunset

Comment: So you need some software that will do ETL process. You need to decide what do you want to use depending on your enterprise architecture.

Comment: You could just add an extra column in your excel file that contains a formula to generate the insert statement for that row. Then copy that column value into a text file and there is your script.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same.

Comment: From Linux you can charge the data with sqlldr. It truncates for you, and do all the actions as fast as possible